# How to make this 'if' statement work after switching to a habtm setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Alright, so I'm very new to rails, so please forgive me if some of these questions seem trivial.

I'm working on a group project in which users view/create the projects that exist, and the projects can display a list of associated users within it. Someone had originally set it up as one-to-many relationship and we had to make it a habtm association.

What I'm asking is how do I make this if statement work that was originally:

```
       <strong><%= project_model.user.name if project_model.user %></strong><br />
      </div>
        <% if project_model.user == current_user %><br />
```

Now project_model should have a database/list within project_model.users (a .build was used when creating the project_model so it should at least contain the current_user. Hopefully....)

Something to note: @project_models is defined in the controller, but this is in a 'do' where @project_models.each do |project_models|

Side note: Some of the things one of my group members did is a little outside the scope of the class and so I'm a bit lost on what some of his code is actually doing. If someone could explain what the project_model.user.name if project_model.user contained within the `<strong>` is actually doing, it would also be really helpful.

Comment: I looked at the many questions you've asked (I also answered to a previous one). Please don't forget to accept or vote on the answers that are given to you, it is an important form of encouragement in stackoverflow community.

Comment: Ah didn't think about that. Sorry. Was sort of still discussing the matter in the comments section of those posts.

Comment: The comments widely exceeds the scope of your questions which have been answered I believe correctly (and I'm not speaking for mine in particular). Giving credit to those answers will not prevent you from asking more questions and getting more help. But you need, and sorry to sound patronizing, to show you're doing some effort on your part before you use comments as a source of information that could be provided by documenting and learning by yourself or in the context of some mentorship.

Comment: Well actually the comments are still dealing with the scope of the question, it's just that because the responses didn't work it sort of leads into why it didn't work. But yes, I will remember to do that from now on. As for the learning by myself, well since I'm trying to work with code set up by another group member (who failed to check or ask with the group), it's less about knowledge and knowing what the hell they were trying to accomplish to begin with, and as for mentorship....Yeah....No one really wants to do that kind of thing pro-bono for somebody, at least not where I'm at anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to find out if `project_model` is associated with `current_user`? If so, try this:

```
project_model.users.exists?(current_user.id)
```

Also, this statement:

```
project_model.user.name if project_model.user
```

is trying to see if `project_model` has an existing associated `user` before attempting to access its `name` property. If the `property_model` does not have a `user`, then `property_model.user` will return `nil`. The `if` statement will treat this as a `false` value and therefore will not execute the code before it. This avoids a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

error if `project_model.user` doesn't exist. However, since you've changed to a habtm association, one `ProjectModel` can have multiple `User`'s. Perhaps you want to use a `project_model.users.each` call to display all of the `users` for the `project_model` instead?

Comment: So if I understand the first part, project_model.users.exists?(current_user.id) checks to see if project_model.users contains the current user right? As for the the second part, are you saying that project_model.users.each if project_model.user would achieve the same effect? I'm not really sure how that if statement needs to be written if that's the case? Edit: I tried adding it and got an error caused from this line: <div class="center"> <%= will_paginate @project_models, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %> </div>

Comment: @gllwrnce What do you want to display for each `project_model` in your `@project_models` collection? Do you want to display information about every `User` that belongs to each `project_model`?

Comment: Yes, for each user in  project_model.user list I need to display them (though I'm not yet sure how to add more already existing users to the list itself, right now I'm trying to display the one that should already be in there, the project creator, supposedly added in creation with @project_model = current_user.project_models.build) Aside from that, just also trying to get the other if statement working

Comment: Just added: 

<% project_model.users.each do |user| %> 

<li> user.email </li>

        <% end %>

Nothing seemed to show up, so an association isn't even being made between the creating user and the project_model.users list at project creation?

Comment: Can you post the controller and view code that handles creating a `ProjectModel`? Also, what "other if statement" are you trying to get working? What is it supposed to do and in what way is it not working? Please be specific.

Comment: Here's the code that handles the project model:     @project_model = current_user.project_models.build


    @project_model.users<<current_user 

For some reason, project_model.users list is still empty. As for the if statements, they're still not working but I'm guessing it's not because you were wrong but because nothing's even in the list to begin with? Not sure why or how that is though.

Comment: The first line builds a new instance of a `ProjectModel` that is associated with `current_user` and stores the instance in `@project_model`. The second line attempts to create an association between this new instance and `current_user`, but the previous line already did that. As to why `project_model.users` is empty, there are several possibilities. Two of these are that `@project_model` wasn't saved or that the `project_model` that you're looking at isn't the one that was just saved. Either way, there are a lot of moving parts here. Can you put your project on GitHub and post the link?

Comment: The project itself is up on github already here: https://github.com/memphis-comp4081/Project-Management-System/tree/GregLawerence   But.... I'm not sure if you'll be able to access it. As for using @project_model.save, if it wasn't already saved how would the new project_model itself exist to be shown in the list?

Comment: I assumed you were saving it and then coming back later to view it. It looks like I can't access your project because it's private.

Comment: Well can I just add you to the project? My professor said not to make it public but that adding your git account would be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for offering to help. Was able to get some help today and seem to have the problem figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written here suggests a `Project` used to have one user (project.user is singular). Now you have many users working on a same project which should translate to: `project.users` (notice `users` is plural) meaning you're dealing with a list of users.

The 2nd `if` statement checks if you're part of a project before showing you stuff only involved users can know. So you can replace:

```
<% if project_model.user == current_user %>
# by
<% if project_model.users.map(&:id).includes?(current_user.id) %>
```

Since we're dealing with a list of users now you also need to iterate through te users you want to display.

So you could replace :

```
<%= project_model.user.name if project_model.user %>
# by
<%= project_model.users.map(&:name).join(", ") %>
```

Comment: So if I understand the first part, project_model.users.exists?(current_user.id) checks to see if project_model.users contains the current user right? 

As for the the second part, are you saying that project_model.users.each if project_model.user would achieve the same effect? I'm not really sure how that if statement needs to be written if that's the case?

Edit: I tried adding it and got an error caused from this line:

      <div class="center">
      <%= will_paginate @project_models, renderer:      BootstrapPagination::Rails  %>
      </div>

Comment: yes to the 1st question (except it's `includes?` not `exists?` ). And yes to the 2nd

Comment: What's the difference between includes? and exists? And any advice about the error being thrown?

Comment: Tried adding exists. The code in the if statement still isn't showing up (it's meant to display links for 'edit' and 'delete' that still aren't showing)

Comment: array.includes?(item) checks if the item is inside the array. exists? checks if an array is empty or not. the error probably comes from not having set paginate on your collection in the controller

Comment: I also updated the answer so it checks on `users` ids and not user itself

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be running the code inside the if statement. Also, what exactly does the second part mean? I'm just trying to learn exactly what the rails logic is saying with these commands.

Comment: oups wasn't aware of exists? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F a perfectly valid answer as well, my bad

Comment: That makes it sound like exists? checks to see if its in the array just like includes? Either way, neither of them is returning true for some reason?

Comment: look at : project_model.users.map(&:id) and current_user.id and check if it's consistent with what you're expecting

Comment: Well thanks to .build I believe that the user who created the project_model should have its id associated with the project_model.user list right? Which is what it should test. Doesn't seem to be working though. Still trying to follow with what you just said, but not sure if I'm quite understanding?